# Why: $\sqrt{z} => φ_\sqrt {z}=\frac {1}{2}φ_z$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let's consider a complex number
z=a+bi, with angle φ
Then why is $φ_\sqrt {z} = \frac {1}{2}φ_z$ ?

So if a complex number z has for example an angle of 90°, then $\sqrt {z}$ has an angle of 45°.

Comment: $z$ can be written as $|z|e^{i\phi}$

Comment: $\sqrt z$ also has an angle of $225^\circ$. This is why you should be _very_ careful with using square root signs on complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple explanation is this: If you take a (non-zero) complex number with argument $45^\circ$ and square it, what is the argument of the result?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I see that it is true. is there also a non-empirical approach when explaining this by using algebra?

Comment: @Stallmp This is _the_ approach, because that's what square root means. Since squaring doubles the argument, square roots must halve them. Any algebra or trigonometry follows from there, not the other way around.

Comment: Okay thanks, I get it now.